# How disk cache works using OkHttp with Picasso

Tags: android, caching, picasso, okhttp

I am using Picasso library for loading images. I know that Picasso doesn't have any disk cache, rather it uses Http Library Cache implementation (in my case it is `OkHttp`). I have few questions about how `OkHttp` manages Disk based caching:
- If the server doesn't send any cache-control headers, would client (`okHttp`) always requests image from the server?
- Does `okHttp` client uses last-modified header to determine if it needs to download the new image.

In our case, the server is not sending any cache-control headers, however i don't want to download image all the time. If the image is changed on the server, last-modified timestamp will be changed and can be used to figure out if the image is updated and then client should download the image.

Another reason for not implementing cache-control headers in this case is, if cache control header says not to download image for 10 days, however if the image is updated after 5 days, the client would not get new image.

Anyone who has used `OkHttp` extensively can please let me know how this library finds if the image on the server is updated and this is the right time to download it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Without any caching headers, OkHttp will fall back to heuristics. There’s lots of explanations of caching rules on the web, but [this one](https://publicobject.com/2015/03/26/how-do-http-caching-heuristics-work/) best describes how OkHttp does it.